# .Net Core with IIS getting 404 on Root Folder

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-8.5

I have an issue with our .net Core API.
We found out, that we recieve every 10 Minutes a call against our root folder from IIS Website. But we do not recieve the call from an external application:
I can see in our logging framework (Application Inisghts) that the call is against localhost: http://localhost/test/MyTestApp/

I can see the folling information in the logs:

- AspNetCoreEnvironment : Production
- Host : localhost
- LoggerName : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
- Method : GET
- Path : /test/MyTestApp/
- Protocol : HTTP/1.1
- Scheme : http

It seems like the IIS is calling the root folder every 10 minutes by self.
But thats only happening with the .Net Core API.

The IIS Looks like this:

[image: IIS]

Comment: If it looks like the picture then the app is not running.

Comment: Sorry thats my fault.
This is just in the image - the error occurs also when the app is running.